# Hive - Extract Arrays dyanmically

Tags: apache-pig, amazon-athena, presto

I have JSON data like below.

```
{
  "userid": null,
  "appnumber": "9",
  "trailid": "1547383536",
  "visit": [{
      "visitNumber": "1",
      "time": "0",
      "hour": "18",
      "minute": "15"
    },
    {
      "visitNumber": "2",
      "time": "2942",
      "hour": "18",
      "minute": "15"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract the visit array values dynamically.

**Like below:** (pipe demited column)

```
userid,appnumber| trailid | 
visit.visitnumber | visit.time | visit.hour | visit.minute | 
visit.visitnumber | visit.time | visit.hour | visit.minute
```

If you see I have 2 json elements inside the visit array. So I want to extract visitNumber, time, hour, minute dynamically. Sometime I may have 3 or 5 values inside the array, so It should extract all 3 or 5 json automatically(I mean dynamically).

Im going to run this on AWS Athena, or may be in Pig Cluster.

Could someone help me with the extact queries?

Comment: In Presto (and so in Athena), query result's columns are statically known upfront, during query planning. The column list cannot depend on JSON keys found in values being retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach but even in this case, all the array entries will be part of different rows.

```
select
userid,
appnumber,
trailid,
d.visitnumber,
d.time, 
d.hour ,
d.minute
FROM table t1
LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE (visit) collection as d;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, But we want all the data in a single row, If you see my expected the current data for visit array has been generated 8 columns ( 4 for first  array element and next 4 for 2nd array element) `visit.visitnumber | visit.time | visit.hour | visit.minute | 
visit.visitnumber | visit.time | visit.hour | visit.minute` . Like this, I have 3 elements then it should generate 12 colums.